# App Advertisement type

Tags: android

I want to know the type of advertisement which is shown on mobile app, in which the advertisement appears till the app loads, e.g. you can take the example of Times of India or Economic times app. I also want to know about the ad networks which provides this type of ads.

Comment: Your question is off topic because it is not about programming and asking for recommendations for sites or products is against SO guidelines. If you have questions regarding specific apps (like this question), you could try to contact the app developers.

Answer (score 0):

That is an inbuilt ad made by the developer after making a deal with vodafone.  No ad network provides that.